# expanding sql query for selecting top two rows based on rating criteria?

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I am doing a few exercises to get my sql basics up. I am stuck here and unable to make any progress further. I would really appreciate if I could get tips on how to break down complex query such as the following:

There are three tables:

Movie ( mID, title, year, director ) -- 
There is a movie with ID number mID, a title, a release year, and a director.

Reviewer ( rID, name ) -- The reviewer with ID number rID has a certain name.

Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )  -- The reviewer rID gave the movie mID a number of stars rating (1-5) on a certain ratingDate.

The problem is :

**For all cases where the same reviewer rated the same movie twice and gave it a higher rating the second time, return the reviewer's name and the title of the movie.**

Here is my attempt:

```
select distinct temp1.ID FROM (select * FROM  
(select rID, name,title twos FROM
(select r.rID , rev.name, m.title, count(*) as twos from reviewer rev
JOIN rating r on r.rID=rev.rID
JOIN movie m on m.mID=r.mID
GROUP BY rev.rID) counts where counts.twos=2) result, rating r 
where result.rID=r.rID ORDER BY ratingDate DESC) TEMP temp1
INNER JOIN TEMP temp2 
ON temp1.rId = temp2.rId AND temp1.ratingDate > temp2.ratingDate
WHERE temp1.stars > temp2.stars;
```

I build this query iteratively. but It did not give right solution. so I would like to know how to approach this kind of problem. 
This is NOT homework.I am doing online tutorial from [here](https://class.stanford.edu/courses/DB/SQL/SelfPaced/courseware/ch-sql/seq-exercise-sql_movie_query_core/).

Thank you

Comment: A question from a course is pretty much the definition of homework ;)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, it helps to think in sets.  For example you could select the set of reviews for which an earlier review with a lower rating exists:

```
select  Reviewer.name
,       Movie.title
from    Rating
join    Reviewer 
on      Reviewer.rID = Rating.rID
join    Movie
on      Movie.mID = Rating.mID
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Rating prev
        where   prev.mID = Rating.mID
                and prev.rID = Rating.rID
                and prev.ratingDate < Rating.ratingDate
                and prev.stars < Rating.stars
        )
```

That's a really nice course btw!

Comment: This works. But what I don't understand is you did not restrict that reviewer has made only two reviews for the same movie but not more..

Comment: If you reviewed a movie thrice, you have also reviewed it twice. The question doesn't say "exactly twice".

Answer (score 1):

First, you get rows with duplicate `mID` and `rID` combination. And then `JOIN` that to `Rating` to see if the second `star` given is higher than of the first. And then `JOIN` to `Movie` and `Reviewer` for the reviewer name and movie title.

```
SELECT
    rv.name,
    m.title
FROM (
    SELECT
        rID, mID
    FROM Rating
    GROUP BY rID, mID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)t
INNER JOIN Rating r
    ON r.rID = t.rID
    AND r.mID = t.mID
INNER JOIN Rating r2
    ON r2.rID = r.rID
    AND r2.mID = r.mID
    AND r2.ratingDate > r.ratingDate
INNER JOIN Movie m
    ON m.mID = r.mID
INNER JOIN Reviewer rv
    ON rv.rID = r.rID
WHERE
    r2.stars > r.stars
```